# JSON file parsing in pyspark - ignore malformed records while creating spark data frame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a spark dataframe where the schema is inferred from json records.But some of the rows of the json data set have more columns than others as a result of which dataframe parsing is failing. Is there anyway I can substitute null values for records where the extra column in missing.

```
raw_event_data_rdd = sc.textFile(INPUT_DATA_DIR)
pre_processed_raw_event_data_rdd = raw_event_data_rdd.map(lambda raw_event: json.loads(raw_event))
rdd_of_rows = pre_processed_raw_event_data_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**x))
pre_processed_raw_event_data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_of_rows,samplingRatio=1,verifySchema=False)
```

My schema is very complicated hence I am using infer schema. How to handle such json data sets with pyspark and convert them to dataframe.

Error :

> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
>   in stage 2.0 (TID 255, adpiaddn-1dd28x-24a87926.us-east-1.amazon.com,
>   executor 49): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have
>   expected number of values required by the schema. 8 fields are
>   required while 7 values are provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqlContext.read.json` to load your json directly into a structured dataframe.

Say we have sample data at `INPUT_DATA_DIR`

```
{"a":1,"b":1}
{"a":2,"b":2,"c":2}
```

Then,

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import json
raw_event_data_rdd = sc.textFile(INPUT_DATA_DIR)
pre_processed_raw_event_data_rdd = raw_event_data_rdd.map(lambda raw_event: json.loads(raw_event))
rdd_of_rows = pre_processed_raw_event_data_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**x))
pre_processed_raw_event_data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_of_rows,samplingRatio=1,verifySchema=False)
pre_processed_raw_event_data_df.show()
```

yields the same error as yours:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 3 fields are required while 2 values are provided.

But,

```
pre_processed_raw_event_data_df = sqlContext.read.json(INPUT_DATA_DIR)
pre_processed_raw_event_data_df.show()

    +---+---+----+
    |  a|  b|   c|
    +---+---+----+
    |  1|  1|null|
    |  2|  2|   2|
    +---+---+----+
```